# Using machine learning to predict data

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, prediction

I want to make a model using machine learning that predicts the number of signups on a given date. I have a training set which contains dates, the number of signups and a couple of other variables/features which may be useful for training this classifier. Also, every 30 days [this trend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0toM.png) is visible.

Ultimately, I would like something like this (using Python):

```
exampledata = [({'date':'01-01-2016','day': 'friday', 'holiday': True, 'etc': 0.3}, 20), ({'date':'02-01-2016','day': 'saturday', 'holiday': False, 'etc': 0.3}, 25),({'date':'03-01-2016','day': 'sunday', 'holiday': False, 'etc': 0.4}, 40)]
classifier.train(exampledata)
classifier.predict("04-01-2016")
>>> 30
```

I've found Scikit's Support Vector Classification method, but I'm not sure how to fit my data in.

How do I get started? If more information is necessary please let me know.

Comment: I would recommend taking a machine learning course to get started.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be a satisfying answer...
You will first have to choose a set of attributes you want to use for the training of the classifier. You will then have to choose a classifier model to learn. And you will eventually have to provide it a training set, a test set and a validation set, which all are subsets of the original set. Many techniques allow to select the model and its parameters that give the best (or less worst) results on prediction afer having learned and tested all of them.

My recommandation would be to use scikit-learn (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) and to take time to get access to its tutorial(s): http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/. You will find there a lot of useful information that should help. How to give training items and their expected results are very well explained there when learning a predictive model.